# Isolate scope - Value defined inside directive scope alone must perform change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I am experimenting with Isolate Scope of Custom Directive.

**A challenging question** I checked with many developer and so far did i not get an answer.

Please find the code from JS Fiddle from Link and help me to correct what changes I should make to get this thing work.

**There is a button inside Directive template** named **My Reverse** "On button click, I want to change text value which is there inside the directive template without affecting the parent value**"

Looking forward for correction in the Fiddle code provided.[Requesting correction to this code sample in JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/own7kbru/6/)

**MORE SPECIFIC CLARIFICATION:**

When i **click on the parent button** i want to **affect the directive textbox value** but when i click on the directive's button i want **to affect only the directive textbox** value **not the parents textbox** value.

---

```
    app.directive("myDirective", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      color: "=",
      reverse: "&"
    },
    template: [
      "<div class='line'>",
      "Name : <strong>{{name}}</strong>;  Change name:<input type='text' ng-model='name' /><br/>",
      "<br/>When I click 'My Reverse' Button, name given inside 'Directive scope' alone must perform reverse operation & not Name inside Parent scope : <input type='button' ng-click='myReverse()' value='My Reverse'/>",
      "</div><div class='line'>",
      "Color : <strong style='color:{{color}}'>{{color|uppercase}}</strong>;  Change color:<input type='text' ng-model='color' /><br/></div>",
      "<br/><input type='button' ng-click='reverse()' value='Reverse Name'/>"
    ].join("")
  };
```

Waiting for a solution.. **please any one help me**.. will be really thankful

Comment: When you click on the parent button you want to affect the directive textbox but when you click on the directive's button you want to affect only the directive textbox , wright?

Comment: Yes exactly, thats what my requirement is - thanks for understanding Dear Theo...

what is the change I should do for that.. can you verify and correct my JSFIDDLE

Comment: Waiting for a solution.. please any one help me

Comment: I checked by clicking on "My Reverse" button. The value is not changing or reversing please check [Please check this JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/t7bxynhq/1/)

Comment: Please take a look on my solution.just ignore my console.logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/arrj2huq/).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Harry";
  $scope.color = "#333333";
  $scope.getReverseName = function(name) {
    console.log('getReverseName', name);
    return name ? name.split("").reverse().join("") : name;
  };
  $scope.reverseName = function() {
    $scope.name = $scope.getReverseName($scope.name);
  };
  $scope.randomColor = function() {
    $scope.color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  };
});

app.directive("myDirective", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      color: "@",
      reverse: "&"
    },
    template: [
      "<div class='line'>",
      "Name : <strong>{{name}}</strong>;  Change name:<input type='text' ng-model='name' /><br/>",
      "<br/>When I click 'My Reverse' Button, name given inside 'Directive scope' alone must perform reverse operation & not Name inside Parent scope : <input type='button' ng-click='myReverse()' value='My Reverse'/>",
      "</div><div class='line'>",
      "Color : <strong style='color:{{color}}'>{{color|uppercase}}</strong>;  Change color:<input type='text' ng-model='color' /><br/></div>",
      "<br/><input type='button' ng-click='reverse()' value='Reverse Name'/>"
    ].join(""),
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.myReverse = function() {
        console.log(scope.name);
        scope.name = scope.reverse({
          name: scope.name
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 20px solid #676767;
  padding: 20px;
}
.parent,
.directive {
  position: relative;
}
.parent:after,
.directive:after {
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.parent:after {
  content: "MainCtrl or Parent Scope";
}
.directive {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #cbccdd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.directive:after {
  content: "Directive Scope"
}
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div class="parent" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="line">
      Name inside parent scope is: <strong>{{name}}</strong>
      <input type="button" ng-click="reverseName()" value="Reverse name" />
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      Color inside parent scope is: <strong style="color:{{color}}">{{color|uppercase}}</strong>
      <input type="button" ng-click="randomColor()" value="Randomize color" />
    </div>
    <div class="directive" my-directive name="{{name}}" color="{{color}}" reverse="getReverseName(name)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool stuff, simple as that in angular way. Thanks a lot @Stepan

Answer (score 1):

I chanded your code so that you can pass value from parent controller to directive by pressing the '**Reverse Name**' button and make the 'Name reverse' by pressing the 'My Reverse' button, **without affecting the parent controller.**

I added the Link function paremeter and inside it, i created the myReverseD() function which is called when you click on 'My Reverse' button.

**so into your directive you have:**

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      color: "@",
      reverse: "&"
    },
    template: [
      "<div class='line'>",
      "Name : <strong>{{name}}</strong>;  Change name:<input type='text' ng-model='name' id='nametxt'/><br/>",
      "<br/>On button click 'My Reverse', I want to reverse text value which is there inside  directive template of isolate scope without affecting the above defined parent Name in Parent scope : <input type='button' ng-click='myReverseD($event)' value='My Reverse'/>",
      "</div><div class='line'>",
      "Color : <strong style='color:{{color}}'>{{color|uppercase}}</strong>;  Change color:<input type='text' ng-model='color' /><br/></div>",
      "<br/><input type='button' ng-click='reverse()' value='Reverse Name'/>"
    ].join(""),
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               console.log(scope.name,scope.color);

               scope.myReverseD = function($ev){

                    var nametxt = document.getElementById('nametxt');
                    console.log($ev);
                    console.log('reverse',nametxt,nametxt.value);

                   nametxt.value = nametxt.value.split("").reverse().join("");       
               }
            }
  };
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/own7kbru/7/

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: Dear Theo, you are great. You saved my day. Was pretty confused Now I got to know the real use of Link function too. Seriously you  are a great teacher. Thanks a lot. Hats off to you.

Comment: Why you use `document.getElementById('nametxt')` instead of  `scope.name`?

Comment: As I watch the second solution , i noticed that the bottom button ,into the directive, 'Reverse Name' doesnt work, is that ok with you Naresh Raj ? because on my solution it works (it changes both controller's & directives input).